# addEventListener trigger all previous instances of array not actual last one

Tags: javascript, ajax

I create a django project where one of elements is form with fields created dynamically by js with data
taken from array. It works fine, but when i prepare the data to send them to the server by ajax I found problem. File I'm preparing is dict. To do it my code after clicking `dodajSkladnikButton` which uses addEventListener function loops through element (`elementyForm`) used previously to prepare form and takes keys from it. Values are taken from inputs of form.
And here is my problem. Mentioned loop try to iterate through all previous instances of `elementyForm` if i don't refresh my page and this generate errors. I assumed than `elementyForm`  should be reseting after generating next form but it doesn't. Problem doesn't occur during creation of form where last instance of `elementyForm` is used at first.

Any Idea what's wrong in my code?

```
     autocompleteButton.addEventListener( 'click', e=>{
            
                              skl=inputBox.value;
                             
                              modalTytul.innerText=inputBox.value;
                               $("#exampleModal").modal('show');
        ///////////////////////////here i create elements of form displayed in modal/////////////
                               
                               $.ajax({
                                type: 'GET',
                                url: `formJson/${ skl }/`,
                                success : function(response){
                                console.log('succes spobrania do forma', response);
                                var elementyForm = response.datadict    
                            elementyForm.map(item=>{
                            if(Array.isArray(item)){if (item[0]==='producent'){
                                const label=document.createElement('label')
                                label.textContent=item[0]
                                label.setAttribute('class','elFormDelete');
                                const select=document.createElement('select');
                                select.setAttribute('class',"ui dropdown");
                                //select.setAttribute('id',"optionId");
                                select.setAttribute('class','elFormDelete')
                                select.setAttribute('id',`${skl}-${item[0]}`)
                                console.log('idwimpucie',`${skl}-${item[0]}`)
                                formBox.appendChild(label)
                                formBox.appendChild(select)
                                //const optionBox= document.getElementById('optionId')
                                const optionBox= document.getElementById(`${skl}-${item[0]}`)
                                const slicedArray=item.slice(1)
                                console.log(item[0])
                                slicedArray.map(elem=>{
                                const option=document.createElement('option')
                                option.textContent = elem
                                optionBox.appendChild(option)
                                })}else{
                                {
                                const label=document.createElement('label');
                                label.textContent=item[0]
                                label.setAttribute('class','elFormDelete');
                                const br=document.createElement('br')
                                br.setAttribute('class','elFormDelete')
                                const select=document.createElement('select');
                                select.setAttribute('class',"ui dropdown");
                                //select.setAttribute('id',"optionId");
                                select.setAttribute('class','elFormDelete')
                                select.setAttribute('id',`${skl}-${item[0]}`)
                                console.log('idwimpucie',`${skl}-${item[0]}`)
                                formBox.appendChild(label)
                                formBox.appendChild(select)
                                formBox.appendChild(br)
                                const optionBox= document.getElementById(`${skl}-${item[0]}`)
                                const slicedArray=item.slice(1)
                                slicedArray.map(elem=>{
                                const option=document.createElement('option')
                                option.textContent = elem
                                optionBox.appendChild(option)
                                })}
                                }
                            }else{
        
        
                            if (item=='aa' || item=='aa_ad'){
                            const label=document.createElement('label')
                            label.textContent=item
                            const check = document.createElement("input");
                            check.setAttribute('type',"checkbox")
                            check.setAttribute('value','off')
                            check.setAttribute('id',`${skl}-${item}`)
                            console.log('idwimpucie',`${skl}-${item}`)
                            check.setAttribute('class','elFormDelete')
                            label.setAttribute('class','elFormDelete')
                            check.setAttribute('name','checkBox')
                            formBox.appendChild(check)
                            formBox.appendChild(label)
                            } else
                            {
                            const label=document.createElement('label')
                            const input=document.createElement('input')
                            input.setAttribute('class','elFormDelete')
                            label.setAttribute('class','elFormDelete')
                            input.setAttribute('id',`${skl}-${item}
                            const br=document.createElement('br')
                            br.setAttribute('class','elFormDelete')
                            label.textContent=item
                            formBox.appendChild(label)
                            formBox.appendChild(input)
                            formBox.appendChild(br)
                            }}
                            })



////////here I create a dict with data from form which I send to server by ajax///////////////  

       dodajSkladnikButton.addEventListener('click',e=>{                
            const checkButtons = document.getElementsByName('checkBox')               
            for (let check of checkButtons){if (check.checked){ check.value='on'}else{check.value='off'}}               
            dataf={'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf[0].value,'skladnik':skl,'receptura_id':sklId}                
            for ( var i in elementyForm )if ( Array.isArray(elementyForm[i])){                 
            dataf[elementyForm[i][0]]=document.getElementById(`${skl}-${elementyForm[i][0]}`).value}

else{dataf[elementyForm[i]]=document.getElementById(`${skl}-${elementyForm[i]}`).value}                
                $.ajax({
                type: 'POST' ,
                url:`dodajskl/${sklId}/`,
                data : dataf,
                success: function(response){
                         console.log('wygrywamy');                         
                         tabelaDocelowa.innerHTML=''
                         updateTable()
                                        },
                error : function(error){                         
                                                  }
                 });                 
                 removeElementsByClass('elFormDelete');
                 $("#exampleModal").modal('hide');
                 })                   
                   },
            error : function (response){
            console.log('error', error)}
            })
         })
```

Comment: sorry that last part of code is green and no  edited but i tried to do this for one hour with no succes:(

Comment: Well, first step is to wrap the anonymous function into a separate callback function. Binding event handler with anonymous function tends to create memory leak since you will be unable to remove the event listener.

Comment: thanks I will try it.

Comment: I didn't expect that would fix it, seems like you were stacking the call everytime the event handler were bound. However, glad you got it working.